# Boogiepop and Others Promotional Trailer references

Tags: boogiepop

2019's "Boogiepop and Others" TV series has a [promotional trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9tu253SOas). However the trailer is kind of "fake", because many footage are not present in the actual TV show.

The main ones are:

- On Opera stage
- A man fighting a fire ability user
- Boogiepop walking closer to another girl, and the background switches with each swing from Boogiepop

Are these referencing other unadapted stories in the series? If yes, which are those?

Answer (score 1):

*Those scenes are highly possibly original materials created exclusively for the trailer.*

[A comment by 'foq fiq'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReGOM4liVPs&lc=UgzHx54bD5hLyNDM7Nd4AaABAg.8tPttbnkGlO8uDK9-JEmFr) on [the Japanese version of the trailer](https://youtu.be/ReGOM4liVPs) mentioned

> 放送決定のイベントでプロデューサーが最後に
> 「あくまで『このくらい本気で作りますよ』ってことを伝えるために作ったティザー用の映像なので本編には出てきません」って言ってた
> 見覚えのない合成人間は原作にも登場しないPVオリジナル
>
> ---
>
> At the end of the event for the broadcast decision, the producer said
> "*After all, because some scenes created for the trailer were to convey that 'we are making it like this seriously', they do not appear on the main story*".
> The unrecognizable characters are trailer-original that do not exist on the source material.

Comment: Note that this is only a blanket answer responding to the 'fake' footages, and this still needs more research on the event detail and if there's a better reference. This *might* not answer the specific question of those scenes, and thus others (who know better about the series) are free to address those specific scenes, which might deprecate this answer.